# How to GET Twitter Ads API Metrics using postman

Tags: twitter, postman, ads, metrics

I'm new to API and I want to get metrics of Twitter Ads such as impressions, clicks, Cost and Leads. I'm using Postman to get these data and I have already the access token for Twitter. Also, I want to pull up these data by the account ID.

Can you help me please...

I have tried this GET method to get the metrics but without any luck:

`https://ads-api.twitter.com/11/accounts/1xxxxxxxxxx6/campaigns/metrics&metric_groups=ENGAGEMENT,WEB_CONVERSION&start_time=2023-10-02T00:00:00Z&end_time=2023-10-08T00:00:00Z&granularity=TOTAL`

This error comes:

```json
"errors": [
        {
            "code": "INVALID_PARAMETER",
            "message": "Expected an id, got \"metrics&metric_groups=ENGAGEMENT,WEB_CONVERSION&start_time=2023-10-02T00:00:00Z&end_time=2023-10-08T00:00:00Z&granularity=TOTAL\" for id",
            "parameter": "id"
        }
    ],
    "request": {
        "params": {
            "account_id": "1xxxxxxxxx6"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates please !

Comment: Url is wrong

You should be doing 
`"https://ads-api.twitter.com/11/accounts/1xxxxxxxxxx6/campaigns/metrics?metric_groups=ENGAGEMENT,WEB_CONVERSION&start_time=2023-10-02T00:00:00Z&end_time=2023-10-08T00:00:00Z&granularity=TOTAL"`

Comment: If you see, url parameters are separated by `?` with path. different url params are seperated by `&`

Comment: When I run this URL you posted, it shows this error: 

 '{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "NOT_FOUND",
            "message": "Campaign metrics was not found for Account 1xxxxxxxxx6",
            "parameter": "campaign_id"
        }
    ],
    "request": {
        "params": {
            "campaign_id": "metrics",
            "account_id": "1xxxxxxxxx6"
        }
    }
}'

Comment: that seems like you are on right direction. can you check campaigns metrics availabile for given account.

Comment: impressions, spend, Link clicks and Leads. these are the metrics available. I have multipule Capmaigns under one account id and i want to get the data of these metrics using get method.

Comment: it seems like i don't have to add metrics? after campaigns/ .. so only campaigns?metrics_group. 
However, none of the metrics_group show, so strange!